# Display the timing of a ruby code block in Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am trying to format my logger output to look like ActiveRecord output and including timing details. For example:

```
User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` LIMIT 1
```

I am not able to figure out how ActiveRecord is doing this. Is there an easy way in Rails to time a code block and display the results nicely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using `benchmark` here's the [Rails guide for profiling](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/performance_testing.html#profiler).

```
Project.benchmark("Creating project") do
  project = Project.create("name" => "stuff")
  project.create_manager("name" => "David")
  project.milestones << Milestone.all
end
```

Result:

```
Creating project (185.3ms)
```

Comment: Thanks @eric-s. That worked. Here is the code I used:  

    `ActiveRecord::Base.benchmark("Message Displayed") do  
      puts "Ruby on Rails"  
    end`